# How to generate List of Id and again List in single list in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to generate List of Tables like

```
new List<Object>()
{
   "Id":123,  
   "columns": List<Object> columnlist
}
```

How can i generate this list There will be multiple lists over here.

Comment: Map it to a type and create list of that type rather

Comment: the question is not cleat, do you mean a list of key value pairs where some of the values will be lists themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better option is here, Create a class with required properties(let it be `Id` and `Columns`) then create a List of Objects of that class: It will be looks this :

Let `myTable` be the class which is defined as :

```
 public class MyTable
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
 }
```

Then the definition for the required list will be :

```
List<MyTable> MyTableList = new List<MyTable>()
{
       new MyTable(){Id=123,ColumnNames=new List<string>(){"Column1","Column2","Column3"}},
       new MyTable(){Id=124,ColumnNames=new List<string>(){"Column1","Column2","Column3"}}
};
```

Comment: @Ash : If it seems helpful then you can mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry dude i don't have more reputation but thanks for help.

Comment: Done for you dude